# Need Help Pinescript V2 to V4

Tags: pine-script

I need to convert this PineScript Study from v2.0 to v4.0.
I don't understand which codes i need to change
i don't know how i can do. I will be glad if you can help with the translation.
I need translation to add the Alarm codes I have.
Thank you in advance for your support

```
//@version=2
strategy(title = "RSI", shorttitle = "RSI", overlay = true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100, pyramiding = 5)

//Settings
needlong = input(true, defval = true, title = "Long")
needshort = input(true, defval = true, title = "Short")
leverage = input(1, defval = 1, minval = 1, maxval = 100, title = "leverage")
limit = input(40, defval = 40, minval = 2, maxval = 50, title = "RSI Limit")

pd = input(22, title="LookBack Period Standard Deviation High")
bbl = input(20, title="Bolinger Band Length")
mult = input(2.0, minval = 1, maxval = 5, title = "Bollinger Band Standard Devaition Up")
lb = input(50, title="Look Back Period Percentile High")
ph = input(.85, title="Highest Percentile - 0.90=90%, 0.95=95%, 0.99=99%")
pl = input(1.01, title="Lowest Percentile - 1.10=90%, 1.05=95%, 1.01=99%")
hp = input(false, title="Show High Range - Based on Percentile and LookBack Period?")
sd = input(false, title="Show Standard Deviation Line?")

fromyear = input(1900, defval = 1900, minval = 1900, maxval = 2100, title = "From Year")
toyear = input(2100, defval = 2100, minval = 1900, maxval = 2100, title = "To Year")
frommonth = input(01, defval = 01, minval = 01, maxval = 12, title = "From Month")
tomonth = input(12, defval = 12, minval = 01, maxval = 12, title = "To Month")
fromday = input(01, defval = 01, minval = 01, maxval = 31, title = "From day")
today = input(31, defval = 31, minval = 01, maxval = 31, title = "To day")

//Vix Fix
wvf = ((highest(close, pd)-low)/(highest(close, pd)))*100
sDev = mult * stdev(wvf, bbl)
midLine = sma(wvf, bbl)
lowerBand = midLine - sDev
upperBand = midLine + sDev
rangeHigh = (highest(wvf, lb)) * ph
rangeLow = (lowest(wvf, lb)) * pl

//RSI
fastup = rma(max(change(close), 0), 7)
fastdown = rma(-min(change(close), 0), 7)
fastrsi = fastdown == 0 ? 100 : fastup == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + fastup / fastdown))

//Body
body = abs(close - open)
abody = sma(body, 10)

//Signals
up = (wvf >= upperBand or wvf >= rangeHigh) and fastrsi < limit and close < open
dn = (wvf >= upperBand or wvf >= rangeHigh) and fastrsi > (100 - limit) and close > open
exit = ((strategy.position_size > 0 and close > open) or (strategy.position_size < 0 and close < open)) and body > abody / 3

//Trading
lot = strategy.position_size == 0 ? strategy.equity / close * leverage : lot[1]

if up
    if strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.close_all()
        
    strategy.entry("Bottom", strategy.long, needlong == false ? 0  : lot, when=(time > timestamp(fromyear, frommonth, fromday, 00, 00) and time < timestamp(toyear, tomonth, today, 23, 59)))

if dn
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.close_all()
        
    strategy.entry("Top", strategy.short, needshort == false ? 0 : lot, when=(time > timestamp(fromyear, frommonth, fromday, 00, 00) and time < timestamp(toyear, tomonth, today, 23, 59)))
    
if time > timestamp(toyear, tomonth, today, 23, 59) or exit
    strategy.close_all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Necessary changes:

1. Change v2 to v4 in the first line
2. the `lot` variable is self-referencing, which is not allowed in v4. It should be declared first and then reassigned with the `:=` operator.

Resulting code:

```
//@version=4
strategy(title = "RSI", shorttitle = "RSI", overlay = true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100, pyramiding = 5)

//Settings
needlong = input(true, defval = true, title = "Long")
needshort = input(true, defval = true, title = "Short")
leverage = input(1, defval = 1, minval = 1, maxval = 100, title = "leverage")
limit = input(40, defval = 40, minval = 2, maxval = 50, title = "RSI Limit")

pd = input(22, title="LookBack Period Standard Deviation High")
bbl = input(20, title="Bolinger Band Length")
mult = input(2.0, minval = 1, maxval = 5, title = "Bollinger Band Standard Devaition Up")
lb = input(50, title="Look Back Period Percentile High")
ph = input(.85, title="Highest Percentile - 0.90=90%, 0.95=95%, 0.99=99%")
pl = input(1.01, title="Lowest Percentile - 1.10=90%, 1.05=95%, 1.01=99%")
hp = input(false, title="Show High Range - Based on Percentile and LookBack Period?")
sd = input(false, title="Show Standard Deviation Line?")

fromyear = input(1900, defval = 1900, minval = 1900, maxval = 2100, title = "From Year")
toyear = input(2100, defval = 2100, minval = 1900, maxval = 2100, title = "To Year")
frommonth = input(01, defval = 01, minval = 01, maxval = 12, title = "From Month")
tomonth = input(12, defval = 12, minval = 01, maxval = 12, title = "To Month")
fromday = input(01, defval = 01, minval = 01, maxval = 31, title = "From day")
today = input(31, defval = 31, minval = 01, maxval = 31, title = "To day")

//Vix Fix
wvf = ((highest(close, pd)-low)/(highest(close, pd)))*100
sDev = mult * stdev(wvf, bbl)
midLine = sma(wvf, bbl)
lowerBand = midLine - sDev
upperBand = midLine + sDev
rangeHigh = (highest(wvf, lb)) * ph
rangeLow = (lowest(wvf, lb)) * pl

//RSI
fastup = rma(max(change(close), 0), 7)
fastdown = rma(-min(change(close), 0), 7)
fastrsi = fastdown == 0 ? 100 : fastup == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + fastup / fastdown))

//Body
body = abs(close - open)
abody = sma(body, 10)

//Signals
up = (wvf >= upperBand or wvf >= rangeHigh) and fastrsi < limit and close < open
dn = (wvf >= upperBand or wvf >= rangeHigh) and fastrsi > (100 - limit) and close > open
exit = ((strategy.position_size > 0 and close > open) or (strategy.position_size < 0 and close < open)) and body > abody / 3

//Trading
float lot = na
lot := strategy.position_size == 0 ? strategy.equity / close * leverage : lot[1]

if up
    if strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.close_all()
        
    strategy.entry("Bottom", strategy.long, needlong == false ? 0  : lot, when=(time > timestamp(fromyear, frommonth, fromday, 00, 00) and time < timestamp(toyear, tomonth, today, 23, 59)))

if dn
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.close_all()
        
    strategy.entry("Top", strategy.short, needshort == false ? 0 : lot, when=(time > timestamp(fromyear, frommonth, fromday, 00, 00) and time < timestamp(toyear, tomonth, today, 23, 59)))
    
if time > timestamp(toyear, tomonth, today, 23, 59) or exit
    strategy.close_all()
```